# Prevent sorting of factor levels

Tags: r, sorting

When I extract the factor levels of a data frame column in R, they are automatically sorted (alphabetically). How can I prevent this? That is, I would like the order of the levels to be identical to the order present in the column of the data frame.

```
data.frame(Names = c("Paul McCartney", "John Lennon")) -> my.data
levels(my.data$Names)
```

> [1] "John Lennon"    "Paul McCartney"

Comment: Why do you need this? Are you dealing with an ordered factor?

Comment: @Roland. Since you ask. I have a column ``X`` in my data frame where only some rows have a value. I want to extract the values in the first column (``Names``) for those rows. I use ``w = my.data[my.data$X!="NA",]$Names``, which returns those values, but also a bunch of ``NA``. So I figured I could get the values I'm interested in by looking at ``levels(w)``, but their order can't change from the original data frame, since I want to match these values with their values from the ``X`` column in the original data frame later. There's probably a better way to go about this ... :-/

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. Make the column a character column and work with that.

Comment: @Roland. I tried that now, but I end up with the same (i.e. a bunch of ``NA`` when I extract the names I'm interested in with ``my.data[my.data$X!="NA",]$Names``) ...

Comment: You check for `NA` with the function `is.na`, e.g., `my.data[!is.na(my.data$X),"Names"]`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Reassign the factor after you read the data:

```
x <- data.frame(x=letters[c(2,1,2)], y=1:3)
x$x
## [1] b a b
## Levels: a b
x$x <- factor(x$x, levels=unique(x$x))
x$x
## [1] b a b
## Levels: b a
```

Comment: I got burnt with this approach as it fails on dates : x <- Sys.Date();factor(x,unique(x)) will return NA with the correct level, to avoid this use factor(x, as.character(unique(x))), it will not change the behavior for character / numeric/logical

Answer (score 2):

If you want to prevent the ordering of factors you need to specifically hand the factor levels over as `levels`:

```
factor(c("Paul McCartney", "John Lennon"), levels = c("Paul McCartney", "John Lennon"))
## [1] Paul McCartney John Lennon   
## Levels: Paul McCartney John Lennon
```

In your case you should create the `factor` before you create the `data.frame` and paste the `factor` in the `data.frame`:

```
f1 <- factor(c("Paul McCartney", "John Lennon"), levels = c("Paul McCartney", "John Lennon"))
my.data <- data.frame(Names = f1)
levels(my.data$Names)

## [1] "Paul McCartney" "John Lennon"
```

Comment: The problem is that in my real case scenario, I'm dealing with a pretty large data set, so this isn't really feasible ...